# Spark - using off-heap memory

Tags: apache-spark

When `spark.memory.offheap.enabled=true`, Spark can make use of off-heap memory for shuffles and caching (`StorageLevel.OFF_HEAP`). Can off-heap memory be used to store broadcast variables? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, **no**, you cannot use `StorageLevel.OFF_HEAP` for broadcast variables.

To understand why, let's look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1485) for the `SparkContext.broadcast(...)` method.

```scala
/**
  * Broadcast a read-only variable to the cluster, returning a
  * [[org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast]] object for reading it in distributed functions ... 
  */
 def broadcast[T: ClassTag](value: T): Broadcast[T] = {
   :
   val bc = env.broadcastManager.newBroadcast[T](value, isLocal)
   :
   bc
 }
```

In the above code, the `broadcastManager.newBroadcast(...)` is what creates the `Broadcast` object, which is the return type of this method.

Now, let's dig deeper and inspect [newBroadcast()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/BroadcastManager.scala#L62).

```scala
def newBroadcast(value_ : T, isLocal: Boolean): Broadcast[T] = {
  broadcastFactory.newBroadcast[T](value_, isLocal, nextBroadcastId.getAndIncrement())
}
```

In the above code, `broadcastManager` has a component called `broadcastFactory` and is using the abstract factory design pattern to delegate the creation of the broadcast variable to its relevant factory.

Also note that the `BroadcastManager` keeps track of a unique `id` for each `broadcast` variable, which is incremented for each new broadcast variable.

Currently, there is only one kind of `BroadcastFactory` that can be initialized in spark, which is the `TorrentBroadcastFactory`. This is seen in the [initialization code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/BroadcastManager.scala#L44) of the `BroadcastManager`.

```scala
// Called by SparkContext or Executor before using Broadcast
private def initialize() {
  :
  broadcastFactory = new TorrentBroadcastFactory
  :
}
```

Quoting the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala#L25) of the `TorrentBroadcastFactory`

> Broadcast implementation that uses a BitTorrent-like protocol to do a
> distributed transfer of the broadcasted data to the executors

This particular factory uses [TorrentBroadcast](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/TorrentBroadcast.scala). The description of this class is very informative.

> The driver divides the serialized object into small chunks and stores
> those chunks in the BlockManager of the driver.
>
> On each executor, the executor first attempts to fetch the object from its BlockManager.
> If it does not exist, it then uses remote fetches to fetch the small
> chunks from the driver and/or other executors if available. Once it
> gets the chunks, it puts the chunks in its own BlockManager, ready for
> other executors to fetch from.   This prevents the driver from being
> the bottleneck in sending out multiple copies of the broadcast data
> (one per executor).

Reading the [writeBlock](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/TorrentBroadcast.scala#L137) function of `TorrentBroadcast` class, we can see the hard-coded `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` options for this broadcast.

```scala
  /**
   * Divide the object into multiple blocks and put those blocks in the block manager.
   *
   * @param value the object to divide
   * @return number of blocks this broadcast variable is divided into
   */
  private def writeBlocks(value: T): Int = {
    import StorageLevel._
    :
    :
    if (!blockManager.putBytes(pieceId, bytes, MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER, tellMaster = true)) {
      throw new SparkException(s"Failed to store $pieceId of $broadcastId " + s"in local BlockManager")
    }
    :
    :
```

Hence, as this code uses hard-coded values of `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`, we cannot use `StorageLevel.OFF_HEAP` for broadcast variables.

Comment: Thanks for a great, very detailed and clear answer! Just a nit -- looks like the driver uses `MEMORY_AND_DISK`, and the rest of the cluster - `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`, correct?

Comment: No problem! Glad this answer has been useful. Yes, that is correct - as per the code, the driver uses `MEMORY_AND_DISK` and executors use `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`. 
I've updated the text in my answer to match what I've shown in the code snippets for coherence.